# Code working in one Addin but doing nothing in another

Tags: c#, revit-api

```
FilteredElementCollector Lincoln = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
Lincoln.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks); Autodesk.Revit.DB.View CurrentView = uiDoc.ActiveView;
ICollection<ElementId> Toggle_On = Lincoln.ToElementIds(); Toggle_On.Clear();
ICollection<ElementId> Toggle_Off = Lincoln.ToElementIds(); Toggle_Off.Clear();
List<Element> Processed = new List<Element>();
List<string> Revit_On = new List<string>(); List<string> Revit_Off = new List<string>();
List<string> Revit_Names = new List<string>();
foreach (Element One_Link in Lincoln)
{
    string Revit_Name = One_Link.Name;
    if (!Revit_Names.Contains(Revit_Name))//prevents processing same link twice;/but does NOT change anyway!!!!
    {
        Revit_Names.Add(Revit_Name);
        Boolean Is_Hidden = One_Link.IsHidden(CurrentView);//
        if (Is_Hidden)
        {
            Toggle_On.Add(One_Link.Id); Revit_On.Add(One_Link.Name);
        }//this apparently does detect what is hidden;
        else
        {
            Toggle_Off.Add(One_Link.Id); Revit_Off.Add(One_Link.Name);
        }
    }
}
Transaction Do_Toggle = new Transaction(doc, "DoToggle");
Do_Toggle.Start();
if (!Toggle_Off.Count.Equals(0)) { CurrentView.HideElements(Toggle_Off); }
if (!Toggle_On.Count.Equals(0)) { CurrentView.UnhideElements(Toggle_On); }
Do_Toggle.Commit();
```

Is somehow the transaction failing?  Undo is not available, so it doesn't think it has done anything that might need to be undone.  Note that this EXACT code is used in another one of my addins (in which multiple optional sub-programs are controlled by picking radio options on a form).  But when I am trying to use the code in a standalone version, it fails (without errors).  Note also that I've inserted multiple TaskDialog entries to verify that it is indeed finding the RvtLinks that are either visible or hidden in the current view.  But it is simply refusing to actually change their visibility.  If I run the dialog controlled version, everything toggles, but if I immediately run the standalone, nothing toggles (proving it isn't uneditable pinned links).  I have made this option available to users by making "Toggle Links" the default so they can call up my collected program and just hit a carriage return, but I need this to be a true standalone.

Answer (score 1):

You code confuses me. For instance, why do you initialise the `Toggle_On` and `Toggle_Off` collections with member values, only to clear them immediately afterwards?

In any case, you use of the transaction does not follow the recommended pattern of enclosing it in a `using` statement.

Please refer to The Building Coder topic group on [Handling Transactions and Transaction Groups](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.53) for more information on using transactions in the Revit API.

Comment: Regarding the Transaction structure, I'm using one that I've seen (and used) in many other programs, including the one where this exact code works -- it is just my standalone where it fails.  Regarding the clearing of Toggle_Off and Toggle_On....I have just gotten in this habit to try and make sure lingering values (such as used by Forms) are totally clear before I start adding them.  I will look at your "Handling Transaction and...." reference, but this still wouldn't explain identical code working in one program and not another (including identical "References").

Comment: So basically, this "Answer" doesn't address the question in the slightest, but simply comments about a code structure that works one place but not another.  This "Answer" confuses me.